# a variable counter in OnCollisionEnter2D is counting only one time but the other line is code working fine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br1A9.png)
im trying to increment the variable "res" but somehow it get increment only one time while the destroy() working fine

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy") )
        {
            res++;
            Destroy(gameObject); 
            Debug.Log(res);
        }
    }
```

need help and thank you .

Comment: When you call `Destroy(gameObject)` you are destroying the gameObject that the collision script is attached to (and all of its components including the instance of the script itself).  Since it no longer exists, it can no longer collide with anything else.

Comment: Is this script on the player? If so how do you respawn the player?

Comment: @ChristophEckinger i don't respawn the player i only do respawn the enemies after sometime with initiate also when i press i initiate a game object called shuriken to collide with an enemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix it is adding a `static` in front of the variable for example from

```cs
public string name;
```

to

```cs
public static string name;
```

`static` turns any variable into a variable that all instances of the class can use and that is the same for all instances. It works as "global" variable.

Comment: Keep in mind this is truly global so you might need a different approach if you ever want to use multiplayer

Comment: yeah simply making things `static` is a dangerous (and a little bit lazy ;) ) approach ^^

Comment: @derHugo Agreed!